# Changing AD passwords of local account without being on company network

Tags: mac, active-directory, osx-mavericks

We've got remote users (who can VPN into our corporate network, but never actually connect to our LAN) who are on Mtn. Lion and Mavericks. If we expire their AD passwords, they can reset them  through the MS Webmail client, but that never resets the password on the local account. When they attempt to reuse their local account passwords through system prefs/users etc., they get a message that the server cannot be reached — even if they're on VPN.

Any ideas on how to synch the new AD password with their old local account password? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think it's a DNS issue where your AD server's IP isn't in your Mac users LAN settings so it has no idea where your AD machine is to synchronise. DNS is crucial in a Windows AD environment.

Answer (score 0):

They should be able to use System Prefs -> Users & Groups while VPNned in. Since this isn't working, I'd concentrate on figuring out why, and fixing it. As Big Chris suggested, DNS the most likely cause. The first thing I'd test is running a ping test (either in Terminal, or the /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Network Utility app) from one of the Mac clients to see if it can find & reach your domain controllers. (The reason I suggest ping rather than a specific DNS test tool, is that most of those bypass the system lookup policy, and therefore can give misleading results.) See if ping can resolve the server names to the correct IP addresses. If the DCs respond to pings, see if that works as well.

If ping fails to resolve the IP addresses correctly, you need to troubleshoot the client DNS setup. Exactly how this should be set up depends on what VPN software you're using, but normally the VPN server should be set up to tell its clients what DNS to use (and that should be an internal DNS server, probably one or more of the DCs), AND the client should be set up to follow the server's instructions.

If the client does resolve the names to IP addresses correctly, something else is going wrong; possibly incorrect routing over the VPN, possibly some internal firewall is blocking access to necessary services on the DC.